# Select from multiple images uploaded to database

Tags: php

I want to select from multiple images uploaded to database and target folder, so i want to select the first image uploaded to display on my homepage:

```
$fetch1 =mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM propertydescription,propertygallery
WHERE propertydescription.propertyID=propertygallery.propertyID ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 10 ");
```

The table consist of 3 columns Userid,PropertyID,Image_Name. The userid is from session while the propertyID is from the current page.

Comment: Please use [edit] to add to your question rather than placing more information in comments. Also, ask the question in the body, not the title. The title should be something short that describes your problem. I have made these edits for you on this post. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `I want to select from …` great. What is your question?

Comment: I want to select from a multiple upload images table . I want to show 1 of the image on my homepage but it has the same userid and propertyID with the remaining images uploaded from the multiple upload.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the minimal information provided, the query you are looking for would be something like:

```
SELECT 
    pg.* # Get the property gallery columns 
FROM propertydescription pd
INNER JOIN propertygallery pg ON pd.propertyID = pg.propertyID
WHERE pd.propertyID = 123
ORDER BY pg.created_at DESC # Not sure what you call this column 
LIMIT 1
```

This will get the most recent row of `propertygallery` as long as it has a property description record where the `propertyID` matches the provided value -- in this case, I just put `123`.